# LWC component on record page does not refresh when flow completes

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a LWC component with three tabs and a quick action button added to an opportunity record page. The quick action button runs a flow and creates or updates a record that would be linked to the currently open opportunity record.

After the flow completes the LWC component on the opportunity record page is supposed to hide two of those tabs which actually works only when I do a reload of the whole browser tab.

How do I make the LWC component refresh after the flow completes?

Please advise!

---

**UPDATE - Added AuraEnabled attribute to Apex method.**

The method call is imperative and I have tried adding the AuraEnabled annotation to the Apex method, but it didn't make any difference at all.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
    public static Boolean selectTabsVisibility(String recordId, String Name) {
         //Some code here
}
```

---

**UPDATE - 11th April 2023 - Added all related calls to the apex class**

**Apex class**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
        public static Boolean selectTabsVisibility(String recordId, String objectApiName) {
             //Some code here
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
import getTabsVisibilityBasedOnObject from "@salesforce/apex/PromoEngineService.selectTabsVisibilityBasedOnObject";
import personalizedTab from '@salesforce/customPermission/Personalized_Offer_Tab';

@track isTabVisible
@track hasPersonalizedTab = false;

calculateTabVisibility() {
        getTabsVisibilityBasedOnObject({recordId : this.recordId, objectApiName: this.objectApiName})
            .then((result)=> {
                this.isTabVisible = result;
                this.setTabVisibility();
            }).catch((error) => {
                handleError({errorKind: ERROR, errorMessage: error});
            });
    }

setTabVisibility() {
        this.hasPersonalizedTab = personalizedTab && this.isTabVisible;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
 <lightning-tabset active-tab-value ="">
            <lightning-tab if:true={hasPersonalizedTab} onactive={handleActive} label="Personalized Offers" value="Personalized Offers">
                <c-promo-engine-personalized-offer 
                    initial-price-role={priceRole} 
                    initial-service-address={serviceAddress} 
                    initial-customer-status={customerStatus} 
                    onsaveoffer={handleSaveOffer} 
                    offer-accept-text={offerAcceptText} 
                    record-id={recordId} 
                    object-api-name={objectApiName} 
                    read-only={readOnly}
                    onbuttonclick={handleupdated} 
                    onpromoengineerror={handleError}>
                </c-promo-engine-personalized-offer>
            </lightning-tab>            
        </lightning-tabset>
```

---

**UPDATE - 13th April 2023 - Using Platform Events**

@Phil W

I have added a platform event and made the LWC subscribe to it on load.

Here are the few extra imports I have added to the JS file

```
import { subscribe as listen, onError } from 'lightning/empApi';
import { getRecordNotifyChange } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

connectedCallback() {
   this.calculateTabVisibility();
}

calculateTabVisibility() {
        getTabsVisibilityBasedOnObject({recordId : this.recordId, objectApiName: this.objectApiName})
            .then((result)=> {
                this.isTabVisible = result;
                this.setTabVisibility();
                this.hasHistory = personalizedTab || inMarketsTab;
                this.refreshList();
            }).catch((error) => {
                handleError({errorKind: ERROR, errorMessage: error});
            });
    }

    refreshList = ()=> {
        listen(this.CHANNEL_NAME, -1, this.testMethod).then(response => {
            this.subscription = response;
            console.log("Response-"+JSON.stringify(response))
        });
        onError(error => {
            console.error('Server Error--->'+error);
        });
        
    }

    testMethod() {
        console.log('Refresh LWC');
        getRecordNotifyChange({ fields: {Id: this.recordId}})
    }
```

I see the Refresh LWC statement on console, but the getRecordNotifyChange() method throws a component error [image]

Comment: How does the LWC access the data it uses to decide what to hide or show? Recall that data can be cached in the front end layer, so you may need to ensure that this cache is cleared (or you need to use a service that doesn't do caching - e.g. an `AuraEnabled` method with `cacheable` set `false`).

Comment: @PhilW currently the tabs are controlled based on the result of an apex call, if the apex call returns true the tabs will be visible and vice-versa. The flow does not have any interaction with this widget or the record page. Would you be able to elaborate on what you mentioned?

Comment: Is the "apex call" made via wire or imperative? If wire, these are always cached. If imperative you can choose to make it uncached with the `cacheable` property in the `AuraEnabled` annotation. See the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_auraenabled_annotation.htm).

Comment: @PhilW I have added an update to the original post, but that change didn't hide tabs when the flow completed.

Comment: You need to add detail showing how the record is updated, how you determine how to show the tabs and the parts of the LWC responsible for showong/hiding the tabs (both the template and the parts of the JS related to calling the Apex and handling the response).

Comment: @PhilW Sorry I had to be away for a while. I have added more details to the original post, let me know if it helps.

Comment: @PhilW hello Phil, would you be able to have a look into the added code?

Comment: I assume it is a copy/paste mistake that the code method names does not match the import method name...

Comment: I also note an inconsistency in parameter names... in the real code or just in the question version?

Comment: I am also a bit concerned over how the custom permission is in use, though would need to double check (am only on phone).

Comment: @PhilW I am using the alias of the apex method inside of javascript, which is actually working. I have corrected the copy/paste errors on the parameter names. And finally regarding the custom permission, it just checks if the custom permission is added to the running users permission set.

Comment: @PhilW I have been trying a lot to make this work. My recent attempt is to use the Platform events. More details have been added to the original post. Please advise.

Comment: @PhilW ignore my last update about using platform events. My team does not want to use platform events.

Comment: I will ignore. Using empApi is, IMHO, not scalable so generally speaking I would not use it. Have you used debugging on the client side and server side to check exactly what flows where and when?

Comment: @PhilW I not continuing here. I have created this post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/401472/refresh-lwc-component-on-opportunity-record-page-using-lightning-messaging-servi as my needs are very specific now.